# Big Query - Case Statements and Apostrophe's

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, nlp

Afternoon, was wondering if anyone is able to assist.

Whilst writing case statements to flag particular phrases in netezza, if we came across verbatim which contained an apostrophe I would get this round this with the below example. However im struggling to recreate this on BQ and wondered if anyone has a solution?

verbatim example : Doesn't have an account

netezza case statement example : when lower(a.case_detail) like lower('%doesn''t have an account%')

Thanks in advance for any helpful suggestions :)

currently not found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two options:

- escape the `'` using backslash `\`: `'%doesn\'t have an account%'`
- use double quotes to start and end the string literal: `"%doesn't have an account%"`

Comment: thankyou very much :)

Comment: @Sdocwra No worries! Could you please accept my answer.

Comment: Think I’ve done it now @ollimandoliini